# Check if file was created today

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a Java program that needs to read from some file. The file should be created only daily and only one time. Another program creates the file. How can I check, using a shell script, that the file was created today (previous midnight/ 12 AM)?

something along the lines of

```
if (file created today)
 // process
else
 // remove old file
 // create new file
 // process
```

The examples I have seen use find command, but I already know the name of the file.

tl;dr

How can I check if file was created today in a shell script? I know the name of file.

Comment: By _today_ do you mean in the last 24 hours or do you mean just since the previous midnight, and if so, do you mean in the current time zone or just UTC?

Comment: I can see why you asked this question. Sorry I was not clear. I meant previous midnight in current timezon. Otherwise, I could have used -ctime /-mtime .

Comment: @anon - wouldn't the script be better (easier) if it was `if (find not created today) remove and create new file; fi; process`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [cron](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cron) to remove/create a file at midnight (if that is what you meant)?

***Or***

When creating the file (when it does not exist) set up [at](http://linux.die.net/man/1/at) at job to delete it in 24 hours (for the other sense)?

Answer (score 2):

You can't, since creation time isn't stored on *nix. You can use `stat(1)` to check the last modification time.